# Why does Liz change her wigs so frequently in the episode "Aus der Tiefe der Zeit"?

Tags: analysis, character, tatort

In the *Dominik Graf* directed [*Tatort*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0806910/) episode ["Aus der Tiefe der Zeit"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2865680/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt) *Liz Bernard* always wears a different wig in nearly each and every scene (the only scene when she doesn't seem to wear a wig is during her interrogation). While sometimes it might just be for special events as part of her job in *Holzer*'s event management company, she does that all the time even during her everyday life and it is never the same wig twice. **But why does she always wear a wig and why always a different one?** What does this behaviour say about her character or her role in the story?

Comment: I have not enough reputation to comment the question so I post a "normal" answer. The official Tatort forum is quite good. http://forum.daserste.de/forumdisplay.php?f=221 Or post your question in another tatort forum http://www.tatort-forum.de/

Comment: @AnkitSharma I know.